# Text align in a DIV that is centered

Tags: css, html

How do I align text to the left on a div that is centered on the screen ?

Comment: `text-align: left`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `margin: auto` to center the `div`, and `text-align: left` to align the text:

HTML:

```
<div class='example'>Hi!</div>
```

CSS:

```
.example {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/RichieHindle/4XHDt/1/

Note that the `text-align: left` isn't necessary in this example because left-alignment is the default.  You only need it if the alignment has been set to something other than `left` by a parent element.

Comment: is there a way to automatically set the width to fit the no-wrap text exactly, in case the text enlarges or shrinks a little? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apply `text-align : left` to your div.

Answer (score 1):

Apply centering to a container, and left-align the inner div:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">left-aligned content goes here</div>
</div>

/* style.css */
#container { text-align: center; }
#content { text-align: left; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Either in your css or as an inline style (not recommended, but it works):

```
text-align:left;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `text-align:left`.

**Note:** Just because the div is centered, doesn't mean the text is centered by default. Take a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/7e7D5/) for an example.

```
#myDiv
{
    width:200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:left;
}
```